# Conditional output in cell based on row data in Gridview's RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a bit value (Black) i want to display its status in gridview as if its true, the row display "Yes", otherwise the row display "No", this is my code, but the result is not right, cuz my code display all rows "Yes" if one value is true, i want to display each row status

```
    protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataTable dt = GetData();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Boolean bitBlack = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[i]["Black"]);
                if (bitBlack)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[7].Text = ("Yes");
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[7].Text = ("No");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the method GetData() returning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always use the rows [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) to get the underlying `DataSource`:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        bool isBlack = row.Field<bool>("Black");
        e.Row.Cells[7].Text = isBlack ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me but in a slighty different context

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to iterate through a DataTable dt on each RowDatabound ?

If you do not need this could you try:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

                Boolean bitBlack = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells[7].Text);
                if (bitBlack)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[7].Text = "Yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[7].Text = "No";
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanx  Seany, but i tried your solution and got the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'"

Comment: Forgot to add the .Text property, please see the revised version of my code with the .Text property added.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your datasource, but if you can evaluate it, do something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemStyle CssClass="list" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# GetBit(Eval("BlackBit"))%>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And code-behind:

```
private string GetBit(object objBit)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(objBit) == 1)
    {
        return "Yes";
    }
    return "No";
}
```

Comment: Tim's answer is working perfect, thanx to all of you for helping