# Adding image to gridview row dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In gridview we have 4 columns

> Asset Type , Asset Name , Asset Description , Icon

Now We want to add image in Icon column,but will be different depending upon the type of the document.
Eg. If asset type is doc then we will display Doc icon;if asset type is jpg then we will display Jpg icon

How to bind different images in each row depending upon the asset type...

Need Help !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the `GridView RowDataBound` method. Access the row `DataItem`, check for the type, and then either dynamically update the ImageUrl of the icon (presuming that your icon is an `<asp:Image>`

Some Reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

[Conditional output in cell based on row data in Gridview's RowDataBound event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666844/gridview-rowdatabound)

Another way would be to create a public function which you could pass in the asset type, and return the URL of the image.

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl='<%#GetImageUrl("imageType")%>'

public string GetImageUrl(string imageType){ 
    //return url 
}
```