# how to change gridview cell color based on cell item using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show a circle inside the Status column and NOT bound to any field in the gridview.  So if Parent ID = 1 then I want to fill the circle with green, if Parent ID = 2 then I want to fill the circle with Yellow and so on.  The Status column should have only the colored circle based on the condition I mentioned.  Also the circle could be some kind of image or something not sure what is the best and easiest way of doing it.  Here is the code that I would like to modify.  Thanks

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
        ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False"
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location"
                SortExpression="Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentID" HeaderText="ParentID"
                SortExpression="ParentID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Content" HeaderText="Content"
                SortExpression="Content" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShortContent" HeaderText="ShortContent"
                SortExpression="ShortContent" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ControlStyle-Width="75px" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParentID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindData();
        }
    }

public void BindData()
    {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Title, Location, ParentID, Content from MyTable", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var item = e.Row.DataItem as DataTable;

            var panel = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("CirclePanel");

            if (item.ParentID == "1")
            {
                panel.CssClass = "yellow";
            }
            else
            {
                panel.CssClass = "green";
            }
        }
    }
```

CSS Style

```
<style type="text/css">
   .green, .yellow { border-radius: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px;} 
    .green, .yellow { -moz-border-radius: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px;}
    .green, .yellow { -webkit-border-radius: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px;} 
    .green, .yellow { -moz-border-radius: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px;} 
    .green { background: green; }
    .yellow { background: yellow; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use css border-radius to display circle icon.

[image]

Note: You could use RowDataBound for your scenario instead of DataBound - it gives you a reference to the current row being bound.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .green, .yellow { border-radius: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px;} 
    .green { background: green; }
    .yellow { background: yellow; }
</style>
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="CirclePanel">
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn
            {
                DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
                ColumnName = "ID"
            });
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn
            {
                DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
                ColumnName = "ParentID"
            });

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = i + 100;
            row["ParentID"] = i;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        int parentID = row.Field<int>("ParentID");
        var panel = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("CirclePanel");
        panel.CssClass = parentID == 1 ? "yellow" : "green";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Win, but i am getting an error where it says "as SomeObject".  I am not sure what you mean by "SomeObject".  Pls halp

Comment: You want cast to appropriate object. If `DataSource` is `DataSet` or `DataTable`, it'll be `e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9667262/296861

Comment: i updated the code behind per your suggestion but it does not like where it says if(item.ParentID==1); to be specific it does not like ParentID.  Pls take a look my updated code behind above.  thanks

Comment: I updated the answer which uses `DataTable` as underlying `DataSource`. I assume that your `ParentID` is an integer. If not, you can change it here - `...row.Field<int>..`

Comment: thank you so much, i got it to working now.  It is showing square shape for the panel in IE but shows a circle in Chrome.  Is there a way to fix that i IE.  I added an updated CSS style in my initial post.  pls see above.  thanks again for all your help

Comment: Rounder corner CSS is not supported in old browser, although most browsers support it.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7077411